# Twitter Bootstrap not showing with laravel controller link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

Hi I am using Twitter Bootstrap Modal to display form without any link modal works fine but when i am giving controller link its not showing modal only showing overlay, i can see in chrome developer tools console proper request and response. here is my code

link

```
<a href="{{ url('sections/create') }}" id="add_section" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal-section"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Section</a>
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade modal-section" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Edited**

when href="#" i can see modal
[image]

when i add url to href to fetch from it show the following.
[image]

Comment: You should add some screens or even demo on http://www.bootply.com/

Comment: i have added screens